# RecyclerView con ItemTouchHelper no funciona

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXAbYWZhpBQ&list=PL65Ccv9j4eZI5xMPqIjABKniid-5X-BgS&index=3) para crear un RecyclerView con ItemTouchHelper, mi RecyclerView funciona bien, sin embargo la implementacion de ItemTouchHelper, parece no funcionar , es decir cuando intento reordenar los items no pasa nada.

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    private var countryList = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var displayList = mutableListOf<String>()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        countryList.add("one")
        countryList.add("two")
        ...
     

        displayList.addAll(countryList)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView )
        recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(displayList)

        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter


        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)


    }


    private var simpleCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP.or(ItemTouchHelper.DOWN),0){

        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            var startPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            var endPosition = target.adapterPosition

            Collections.swap(displayList, startPosition, endPosition)
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemMoved(startPosition, endPosition)
            return true

        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        }

    }

}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
class RecyclerAdapter(countryList: MutableList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> () {

    private var countries: MutableList<String> = countryList
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemTitle.text = countries[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countries.size
    }

    inner class  ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var itemImage: ImageView
        var itemTitle: TextView

        init {
            itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage)
            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle)

        }
    }
}
```

En este caso igua que en el video solo estoy habilitando el movimiento de posición "ItemTouchHelper.DOWN"  y ItemTouchHelper.UP, he visto algunos ejemplos donde añaden ItemTouchHelper.END y ItemTouchHelper.START sin embargo también he intentado usarlos pero el problema persiste.
Hay algo que este haciendo mal, he revisado el proyecto y todo parece tener sentido, no se genera ningún error simplemente no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que le falta a tu código es establecer `recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)` después de `recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter`.

Por lo demás debería funcionar. Básicamente he copiado y pegado tu código en un proyecto nuevo.

¿Podría estar el problema en el Layout? Te dejo el Layout que he hecho con CardView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/itemImage" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Otra cosa, no sé si servirá pero `var endPosition = target.adapterPosition` debería ser `adapterAbsolutePosition` ya que el primero está deprecado.

Comment: Finalmente, descubrí que pasaba. 
Si estaba funcionando correctamente, el problema era que yo estaba intentando arrastrar los elementos sin mantenerlos presionado, por ello no pasaba nada.
Gracias por tu apoyo.